# How to put value of Dash-Plotly dropdown to a python variable?

Tags: python-3.x, drop-down-menu, plotly-dash

I was able to print the value of the dropdown using a callback. Is there any way to put this value in a python variable?

[image: Dash Dropdown Example]

I want to use it (turkey) in an API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the value in a callback, then it already is a Python variable. I assume you did something similar to this?

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('my-output', 'value')
    Inputs[('my-input', 'value')])
def callback_func(dropdown_value):
    print(dropdown_value)
```

You can use `dropdown_value` here in that function just like any other Python variable. It is limited to the scope of the function, but you could do things to make it accessible elsewhere, just like with other variables in functions. You could write it to a file, add it to a list or dict from some other context, and so on.

Comment: I managed to store the value to variable outside the function. However, once that is done, I want to run the entire script again, is there a way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by run the script again? The Dash server should continue to run, and the callback will fire every time the dropdown value changes, allowing you to manipulate it each time.